# Symfony2 - Avoid assets:install copy to web scss

Tags: symfony, assets, assetic

My SCSS files are being copied to `/web` folder when I'm using `php app/console assets:install`

I really need to do this due to vendor's bundles.

Basically, I need to avoid being copied **all files** that Assetic uses.

Comment: Try not to put your `scss` files in the `public` directory.

Comment: Please define *all files* in this context. Do you mean that `scss` files are copied instead of only the computed files (e.g. CSS files merged as only one file).

Comment: Like [chapay](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4399592/chapay) said, i think i'm going to put all my scss out of public directory. Same for my js that are going to be minimized.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Symfony 2.6

```
# make a hard copy of the assets in web/
$ php app/console assets:install

# if possible, make absolute symlinks in web/ if not, make a hard copy
$ php app/console assets:install --symlink

# if possible, make relative symlinks in web/ if not, make a hard copy
$ php app/console assets:install --symlink --relative
```

from http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-smarter-assets-install-command

Comment: I know how to install assets. The problem comes with assetic and my scss files that are dumped. Not to mention that also my js files are being duplicated.

Comment: That's why the --symlink option is made for

Comment: OP's question has nothing to do with `--symlink`.